# Complex Grouping Query

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Below is my sql query, I have put some MAX(table_name) because when group by is used I can't just put the table name. If I put MAX, it will take time to execute when there is varchar values, please give me good aggregate function for varchar instead of MAX.

Also, those MAX(table_name) all are same values, no different, I just need to print it.

```
select distinct 
    t1.PartyName as Customer_Name, 
    SUM(t2.Amount) as Bill_Amount, 
    MAX(t2.VoucherNumber) as Invoice_Number, 
    SUM(i.Weight * t2.Aqty) as Weight, 
    CEILING(SUM(i.CBM * (t2.Aqty/c.Nos))) as CBM, 
    MAX(p.Channel) as Type, 
    MAX(p.RouteNo) as RouteNo, 
    MAX(t1.Adress3) as City
from 
    Item i, 
    Party p, 
    Tran1 t1, 
    VTran2 t2, 
    Cases c
Where 
    t1.VoucherNumber=t2.VoucherNumber and 
    t2.ItemName=i.Itemname and 
    p.PartyName=t1.PartyName and 
    t2.ItemName=c.ItemName and 
    p.RouteNo='" + routeNo1comboBox.Text + "' and 
    t1.LoadingStatus IS NULL and 
    t1.Date BETWEEN '" + startDate + "' and '" + endDate + "' 

GROUP BY t1.PartyName
```

Comment: Your `join` conditions are probably wrong.  Fix your query to use propoer `join` syntax, and that might fix your problem.

Comment: If `table_name` is the same for all records then why do you need to perform an aggregate function on it, just include it in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your response, can you provide me small modification with my example with join? After that I can catch easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Also, those MAX(table_name) all are same values, no different, I just need to print it."

Why can't you just add them in the select list and the group by also ?

This one does not work ?

```
select distinct 
    t1.PartyName as Customer_Name, 
    SUM(t2.Amount) as Bill_Amount, 
    t2.VoucherNumber as Invoice_Number, 
    SUM(i.Weight * t2.Aqty) as Weight, 
    CEILING(SUM(i.CBM * (t2.Aqty/c.Nos))) as CBM, 
    p.Channel as Type, 
    p.RouteNo as RouteNo, 
    t1.Adress3 as City
from Item i, Party p, Tran1 t1, VTran2 t2, Cases c
Where t1.VoucherNumber=t2.VoucherNumber 
and t2.ItemName=i.Itemname 
and p.PartyName=t1.PartyName 
and t2.ItemName=c.ItemName 
and p.RouteNo=''' + routeNo1comboBox.Text + ''' 
and t1.LoadingStatus IS NULL 
and t1.Date BETWEEN ''' + startDate + ''' and ''' + endDate + ''' 
GROUP BY t1.PartyName, cs,t2.VoucherNumber,p.Channel,p.RouteNo,t1.Adress3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexandru Aliu for your simple and easy modification solution.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add `distinct` since you are already grouping by t1.PartyName,t2.VoucherNumber,p.Channel,p.RouteNo,t1.Adress3.

```
select 
    t1.PartyName as Customer_Name, 
    SUM(t2.Amount) as Bill_Amount, 
    t2.VoucherNumber as Invoice_Number, 
    SUM(i.Weight * t2.Aqty) as Weight, 
    CEILING(SUM(i.CBM * (t2.Aqty/c.Nos))) as CBM, 
    p.Channel as Type, 
    p.RouteNo as RouteNo, 
    t1.Adress3 as City
from Item i, Party p, Tran1 t1, VTran2 t2, Cases c
Where t1.VoucherNumber=t2.VoucherNumber 
and t2.ItemName=i.Itemname 
and p.PartyName=t1.PartyName 
and t2.ItemName=c.ItemName 
and p.RouteNo=''' + routeNo1comboBox.Text + ''' 
and t1.LoadingStatus IS NULL 
and t1.Date BETWEEN ''' + startDate + ''' and ''' + endDate + ''' 
GROUP BY t1.PartyName, cs,t2.VoucherNumber,p.Channel,p.RouteNo,t1.Adress3
```